# Add an index for duplicate names

Tags: python-3.x

with the following code I get :

```
>>> for leaf in tree:
...     print(leaf.name)
... 
IDBA_scaffold_Genus1_species1
IDBA_scaffold_Genus1_species1
IDBA_scaffold_Genus1_species2
IDBA_scaffold_Genus3_species1
IDBA_scaffold_Genus3_species1
```

and I would like to do something like:

```
for leaf in tree:
 if duplicate leaf.name:
    then add an index to this leaf.name 
    leaf.name = leaf.name+index
```

and then for the exemple I should get :

```
>>> for leaf in tree:
...     print(leaf.name)
... 
IDBA_scaffold_Genus1_species1_index1
IDBA_scaffold_Genus1_species1_index2
IDBA_scaffold_Genus1_species2
IDBA_scaffold_Genus3_species1_index1
IDBA_scaffold_Genus3_species1_index2
```

the leaf.name in leaf can be in a list or in a column as well.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: create a 'set' and add the leaf.name in the set. At every iteration, check if the leaf.name is already present or not. then do if-else logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# When comparing, record the previous name
prev_name = None
index = 0

for leaf in tree:
    # Skip the first one, starting with the second one, comparing whether the first two names are consistent
    if prev_name is not None:
        if prev_name == leaf.name:
            index += 1
            print(prev_name + '_index' + str(index))
        else:
            # If the two are not equal, and the index is greater than 0, the previous name is duplicated before, but it is not duplicated with the current name.
            if index > 0:
                print(prev_name + '_index' + str(index + 1))
                index = 0
            else:
                print(prev_name)
    prev_name = leaf.name

# Finally, the last data in the traversal is processed.
print(prev_name + '_index' + str(index + 1) if index > 0 else prev_name)
```

**Edit**: add notes